# Roland FP-10 usb connection and charging -- which way?

Tags: digital-piano

I've just learned that with digital piano and MIDI-to-USB connection the cable or converter is an active element and it is charged not from digital piano (MIDI side) but from tablet/computer (USB side).

Thus the question (to be 200% sure) -- if I connect Roland FP-10 via USB (pure USB, because this model does not have MIDI, just regular USB) with tablet:

1. the tablet will be charged by FP-10
2. FP-10 will be "charged" by tablet (more precisely tablet will discharge itself attempting to charge FP-10)
3. there will be no charging any way

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your first paragraph:

The MIDI-to-USB converter being an ‘active element’ means that the converter *itself* needs power.

MIDI doesn't carry power (only a ground, and a balanced pair for the signal).  But USB must provide power (at least 5V 100mA, usually 0.5A or more).  So **the converter must take its power from the USB connection**.  (However, it's unlikely to have an internal battery, so there's nothing to ‘charge’.)

In fact, the MIDI signal is electrically separated with an opto-isolator, so even if it did carry power, there would be **no way to transfer power between the ends of a MIDI cable**, regardless of whether it connected to a USB converter or directly into another device.

However, your second paragraph is about a direct USB connection between devices…

USB *can* carry power.  However, it's directional.  (Before USB ‘C’, this was enforced physically: ‘hosts’ such as computers and hubs had A-type sockets, while devices such as printers had incompatible B-type sockets, and cables would always have an A-type plug at one end and a B-type plug at the other.)  In general, I think the host must provide power for the device to use, never vice versa — and since the computer or tablet must be the host, then it can't receive power from the electric piano.

More recent USB versions have added more flexibility for charging, but **the Roland FP-10 has only a traditional USB B-type socket, so it won't be able to provide power through it**.

All of which points to your option 3 (no charging), either way!

Comment: Thank you for such in-depth answer.

Comment: I don't believe the part about the host is right. With USB C you can have host being charged by the peripheral device. For example, a laptop can be charged by a docking station. That being said, I haven't heard of musical instruments making use of that... but perhaps that's coming? The OP's example with a piano and a tablet actually would seem quite practical.

Comment: @user1079505 As I said, more recent versions of USB have a lot more flexibility about the direction, voltage, and current you can use to charge things.  ([USB Power Delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#USB_Power_Delivery) is the main standard, though there are others including several proprietary ones.)  I can't find any information on when the FP-10 was introduced or which USB version(s) it supports — but the fact that it uses an old-style B-type port, and doesn't mention USB2 or USB3 suggests it's only original USB (1), which didn't have any of that.

Answer (score 2):

Such functionality would be mentioned in the manual. As I couldn't easily find anything regarding charging via USB, I would assume there is no charging in either direction.

From my experience, this is a regular behavior of larger pianos with speakers and dedicated power adapter, like FP-10. In turn, MIDI keyboards, which produce no sound or audio signal on their own, often draw the power from the USB cable.

I haven't heard of an instrument that could provide power to the tablet. I think the name of such functionality would be *power delivery*.

Comment: Many thanks. Just clarification, I didn't mean solely MIDI controller in the opening sentence, just digital piano which does not have USB, so usually you end up buying some MIDI-to-USB kit to connect it computer/tablet/etc.